# Адаптировать античит игры под linux

Tags: linux, windows

Здравствуйте помогите разобраться с темой. Есть игра lineage2 там есть античит, который работает только для windows а я хочу попробовать запустить игру под linux. Соответственно надо как то адаптировать этот античит, потому что только он не пускает в игру. Какие есть способы дизасемблирования или как это делают? Хочу просто разобраться в вопросе, и куда копать по данной теме?

Answer (score 1):

> Какие есть способы дизасемблирования или как это делают?

Здесь даны ссылки на несколько дизассемблеров для Windows:

https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B